# agent cannot be resolved to a variable in function body but works in other blocks

Tags: anylogic

I currently have a function that gets checked at certain time intervals. I want a `hold` to unblock upon satisfaction of the condition in the function body. However, `agent` can never be resolved to a variable, even though this convention of referring to the agent works in other process blocks. The `agent` that is present in the `(((Patient)agent)` is the agent that cannot be resolved to a variable. Patient is an agent type and has the variable `isMorning` that gets set to true or false upstream in the model. Below is the code in the function block, and the parameters are set to Just action (returns nothing). The `(((Patient)agent)` would be in a queue block prior to the `hold`.

```
if (((Patient)agent).isMorning == true && SurgeonMorning.idle() > 0){
    hold.unblock();}
else if (((Patient)agent).isMorning == false && SurgeonAfternoon.idle()  == 0){
    hold.unblock();}
```

Comment: in what block are you using this? show a picture of the process?

Comment: It is in a function block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is code in a function, you need to provide a function argument and use that instead of `agent`.

In the properties of the function under arguments, add an entry `myPatient` and specify the type as `Patient` (right side from the dropdown).

Then, you can use the code as

```
if (myPatient.isMorning == true && SurgeonMorning.idle() > 0){
    hold.unblock();}
else if (myPatient.isMorning == false && SurgeonAfternoon.idle()  == 0){
    hold.unblock();}
```

Check the help to understand functions more. And this article to understand when (and when not) you can use these little keywords like `agent`: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling